# Prometheus Alertmanager authorization token

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm looking for how to pass authorization tokens using Prometheus Alertmanager.

My configuration is, and I have got the error `unexpected status code 401:`

```yaml
- name: 'msteamsdesktop'
    webhook_configs:
    - url: 'https://d.teamwork.com/tasklists/111111/tasks.json'
      send_resolved: false
      http_config:
        authorization:
          credentials: 'bSDVkTG5UdkNydQ=='
```

For `curl`, it looks like that.

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url https://ht.io/s/teamwork/4908/tasklists/id/tasks.json \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic undefined' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{.....
```

Comment: The Prometheus config you show uses the Bearer (default for `authorization`) scheme  i.e. `Authorization: Bearer bSDVkTG5UdkNydQ==` but the `curl` example uses the Basic scheme. The Prometheus config should reflect the `curl` example if that works? i.e. use `basic_auth` and not `authorization`. See [<http_config>](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#http_config)